# Missing required attribute severity in <apex:pagemessage>

Tags: apex, visualforce

When list size is 0 show info message on vfpage but while saving vfpage its throw an error "missing required severity-- I have mark severity in class already

```
if(conlist.size() == 0 ) {
    Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,''+'No records found.'));
    return null;
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:pagemessage> </apex:pagemessage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<apex:pagemessage> </apex:pagemessage>
```

Instead of this you can use(add s in end)

```
<apex:pagemessages> </apex:pagemessages>
```

Because Severity is required attribute of `apex:pagemessage`. As you have already specified is in class so you can use `apex:pagemessages`

> The Values supported are: 'confirm', 'info', 'warning', 'error'

You can check more about [apex:pagemessage here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessage.htm)

> apex:pagemessage is meant for hard-coded messages in a page whereas
>   apex:pagemessages is meant to present the zero or more messages that
>   you add in the controller (and so is used much more often).

Comment: Think its worth saying that `apex:pagemessage` is meant for hard-coded messages in a page whereas `apex:pagemessages` is meant to present the zero or more messages that you add in the controller (and so is used much more often).

Comment: @TusharSharma my requirment is to used apex:pagemessage because i have set many places in vfpage <apex:pagemessages> only 1 per page but <apex:pagemessage> can be multiple

Comment: @cloudZigZag why you need multiple pagemessage. They all have same funtionality. Single  ` apex:pagemessages` can achieve that as well. Also you can use multiple `apex:pagemessages` as well. there is no such limit.